# Использование полиморфизма в Java

Tags: java, полиморфизм

Только изучаю Java, не будьте строги.
Есть код

```
    class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A a = new B();
            a.method(100);
        }
    }
    
    class A {
        public void method(Object obj) {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }
    
    class B extends A {
        public void method(Integer obj) {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }
```

При вызове `a.method(100);`я ожидал получить "B", т.к. `a` является объектом класса `B`. Но в результате получаю "A". Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, вы ждёте, что сработает диспетчеризация методов и вместо метода предка будет вызван метод потомка потому, что имеет место переопределение, и у вас по факту new создал экземпляр потомка.

Вы очень правильно мыслите, но тот, кто дал вам это задание, постарался вас подловить.

Здесь не происходит переопределения метода в потомке. Попробуйте добавить аннотацию и код не скомпилируется:

```
class B extends A {
    @Override //Compilation error
    public void method(Integer obj) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

А значит никакой диспетчеризации и выполнения методов потомка вместо методов предка.

Эти методы имеют разную сигнатуру:

```
public void method(Object obj) 
public void method(Integer obj)
```

А значит у вас обычная перегрузка, а не переопределение.

А раз метод не переопределён в потомке и у вас переменная типа предка, то и вызывается метод предка.